# collect negative samples of adaboost algorithm for face detection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection, adaboost

Viola-Jones' AdaBoost method is very popular for face detection? We need lots of positive and negative samples o train a face detector.

The rule for collecting positive sample is simple: the image which contains faces. But the rule for collecting negative sample is not very clear: the image which does not contains faces.

But there are so many scene that do not contain faces (which may be sky, river, house animals etc.). Which should I collect it? How can know I have collected enough negative samples?

Some suggested idea for negative samples: using the positive samples and crop the face region using the left part as negative samples. Is this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have asked many questions inside your thread.

1. **Amount of samples**. As a rule of thumbs: When you train a detector you need roughly few thousands positive and negative examples per stage. Typical detector has 10-20 stages. Each stage reduces the amount of negative by a factor of 2. So you will need roughly 3,000 - 10,000 positive examples and ~5,000,000 to 100,000,000 negative examples.
2. **Which negatives to take**. A rule of thumb: You need to find a face in a given environment. So you need to take that environment as negative examples. For instance, if you try to detect faces of students sitting in a classroom than take as negative examples images from the classroom (walls, windows, human body, clothes etc). Taking images of the moon or of the sky will probably not help you. If you don't know your environment than just take as much as possible different natural images (under different light conditions).
3. **Should you take facial parts** (like an eye, or a nose) as negative? You can but this is definitely not enough (to take only those negatives). The real strength of the detector will come from the negative images which represent the typical background of the faces
4. **How to collect/generate negative samples** - You don't actually need many negative images. You can take 1000 images and generate 10,000,000 negative samples from them. Here is how you do it. Suppose you take a photo of a car of 1 mega pixel resolution 1000x1000 pixels. Suppose than you want to train face detector to work on resolution of 20x20 pixels (like openCV did). So you take your 1000x1000 big image and cut it to pieces of 20x20. You can get 2,500 pieces (50x50). So this is how from a single big image you generated 2,500 negative examples. Now you can take the same big image and cut it to pieces of size 10x10 pixels. You will now have additional 10,000 negative examples. Each example is of size 10x10 pixels and you can enlarge it by factor of 2 to force all the sample to have the same size. You can repeat this process as much as you want (cutting the input image to pieces of different size). Mathematically speaking, if your image is of size NxN - You can generate O(N^4) negative examples from it by taking each possible rectangle inside it.
5. In step 4, I described how to take a single big image and cut it to a large amount of negative examples. I must warn you that negative examples should not have high co-variance so I don't recommend taking only one image and generating 1 million negative examples from it. As a rule of thumb - create a library of 1000 images (or download random images from Google). Verify than none of the images contains faces. Crop about 10,000 negative examples from each image and now you have got a decent 10,000,000 negative examples. Train your detector. In the next step you can cut each image to ~50,000 (partially overlapping pieces) and thus enlarge your amount of negatives to 50 millions. You will start having very good results with it.
6. **Final enhancement step of the detector**. When you already have a rather good detector, run it on many images. It will produce false detections (detect face where there is no face). Gather all those false detections and add them to your negative set. Now retrain the detector once again. The more such iterations you do the better your detector becomes
7. **Real numbers** - The best face detectors today (like Facebooks) use hundreds of millions of positive examples and billions of negatives. As positive examples they take not only frontal faces but faces in many orientations, different facial expressions (smiling, shouting, angry,...), different age groups, different genders, different races (Caucasians, blacks, Thai, Chinese,....), with or without glasses/hat/sunglasses/make-up etc. You will not be able to compete with the best, so don't get angry if your detector misses some faces.
   Good luck

Comment: Awesome answer! One more question: must negative samples be the same size?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, If you train your detector on a given resolution (say 20x20 pixels or 24x24 - typical for faces) - all your positive AND negative examples must be resized to this exact resolution, same format (typicaly grey level, without color)

Comment: What is meant by **In the next step you can cut each image to ~50,000 (partially overlapping pieces) and thus enlarge your amount of negatives to 50 millions.** ? @DanielHsH

Comment: Say you have an image of size 1000x1000 and you want to cut it to pieces of non overlapping 20X20 pixels. You will get ~2500 images. If you allow overlaping of 10 pixels between those 20x20 patches you will get ~10,000 pieces. All are example of non face. If you also allow patches of different sizes: you can get to higher numbers. When you take a picture of non faces the picture itself is a negative example, as well as any cropped region. So a single image can generate many non face examples by cropping it.